# STM32 BluePill LED flasher acts strange using HAL_GPIO_TogglePin

Tags: stm32, bluepill

I have two simple LED flasher programs the flash at 1 sec intervals for my BluePills.One method uses HAL_GPIO_TogglePin to toggle the LED state and the other uses Set and Reset to toggle the LED state. The Set and Reset functions as expected but the HAL_GPIO_TogglePin definitely is working but it has a almost PWM effect part of the time. I have tried both methods on 2 different Bluepills with same results for both.

```
 while (1)
  {  
        if (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim1) >= 32000)
        {
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(User_LED_GPIO_Port, User_LED_Pin);
        }
```

and

```
 while (1)
  {  
        if (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim1) >= 32000)
        {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(User_LED_GPIO_Port, User_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }
        else {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(User_LED_GPIO_Port, User_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
```

Comment: You didn't mention how the timer is configured. Let's assume it counts to 64,000. So looking at your first code snippet: from 0 to 32,000, the LED is not changed. From 32,000 to 64,000, the LED is changed (toggled) on every loop iteration, possibly several thousand times a second, i.e. it looks like PWM. Your code matches exactly what you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Codo, you were 100% right. I modified it to

```
if ((__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim1) == 32000) || (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim1)==0))
        {
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(User_LED_GPIO_Port, User_LED_Pin);
          timer_val = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim1);
        }
```

Funny thing is I originally followed the Digikey example and it did the same thing.

```
  while (1)
  {
    // If enough time has passed (1 second), toggle LED and get new timestamp
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim16) - timer_val >= 10000)
    {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
      timer_val = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim16);
    }
```

oh well, for what i want, the Set Reset works better anyways. Thanks